# How can I compute the following fast?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, modular-arithmetic

What approach should I adopt for computing the following problem fast?

$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (n \mod i)$$
$$ 1\le n \le 10^{10}$$

Since the answer can be huge I have to output it modulo some given number *m*.

$$ 1\le m \le 10^{5}$$

Note that, a fast method to compute the above will suffice, and a closed form expression may not be necessary.

Comment: What competition is it? Some competitions (like Euler) would consider asking for help cheating.

Comment: @gnasher729 This is not from any competition. I faced a problem somewhere and thought about this one.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start at $i=n$, and go backwards towards $0$. What is the remainder of *n* when divided by *n*, $n-1$, $n-2$, etc. ? At what value of *i*, relative to *n*, does this behaviour stop ? [What formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples) could we use to directly compute the afore-mentioned partial sum ? Using the above insight, how can the remaining interval be partitioned or subdivided ?

Comment: Will not work for smaller i (there is no well defined behaviour), and anyway I am required to loop over the entire n, which will be slow.

Comment: @aceBox: If you say so...